# Confirm the action during the execution of the script run by Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins

I set up the task in Jenkins, but I don't know how to do automatic confirmation during command execution.

While the script is running, there will be a request

```
Install by path /home/user/file
```

And you need to press enter
Is it possible to force Jenkins to "press enter" automatically, for the script to work fully automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to enter yes for a particular prompt and its not specific to Jenkins.
suppose you are running this command in shell block, you can just run it as below and it will automatically say yes to prompt -

```
echo | yourcommandhere
```

you can also utilize Yes command or expect in script as per the requirement.

```
yes "" | yourcommandhere
```